# Finding ideal filter setting to maximize target function

Tags: r, optimization, filter, combinations, grid-search

I have a real dataset which is huge and within this I have 4 columns (numerical data in the range of -10 to +10) which I can use to filter the data. Any amount of filters can be used simultaneously and any setting for the filters in the form (>, < a certain value per filter in 0.5 increments) can be used to split the data. Target is to mazimize the average of the filtered values in the Size column while considering n must at least be 5.

I tried to find all combinations of the filters (e.g. A>1, B<-2 or A AND C>0.5, etc.) but I am stuck to find an optimal solution with an algorithm and not just try and error. Trying all combinations in brute force is also no solution as the dataset is huge and therefore the calculations do not end in a resonable time.

How would you go about this "grid search" in 4 dimensions?

Here a reduced example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(~Size, ~A, ~B, ~D, ~E,
          1, "4", "7", "-2", "1",
          5, "-4", "-1", "1", "4",
          10, "-2", "-3", "1", "9",
          -3, "1", "0", "0", "-3",
          2, "4", "-1", "3", "-2",
          55, "8", "-7", "9", "0",
          -5, "3", "-4", "-1", "-5",
          2, "0", "-2", "1", "8",
          1, "-5", "1", "8", "1",
          4, "-9", "3", "2", "-3")
```

Comment: What is your desired output for the given example?

Comment: The example is a very reduced form of the real problem. The solution should contain which filters need to be applied (in the form of >, < with 0.5 increments) and with that settings to reach the highest average Size considering at least 5 samples. So for example setting filter A>0.5, would yield an average Size of (1+-3+2+55+-5)/5 =  10. This would be a canditate solution.

Comment: Do all columns have to be used in the filter? In any case, you could use a heuristic, e.g. a Local Search, to solve this problem. The advantage is that such a method would allow you to implement your problem directly, without having to transform it in any way. (See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159342/non-linear-fitting-with-nls-is-giving-me-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-p/56211148#56211148 )

Comment: If I understand correctly, E > -1.5 would be a better solution than A > 0.5?

Comment: @EnricoSchumann: Thank you for the suggestion. At least one and maximum all 4 variables can be included. I checked the link but how would you implement a local search algorithm for this problem?

Comment: @JosephWood Target is to find the ideal filter settings in the columns A,B,D,E as described above in order to mazimize the average of the filtered values in the Size column while considering n must at least be 5.

Comment: I've been thinking about this off and on for the past 2 days. It's a tough problem. One thing I've considered is looking at this upside down. We first pick a set from Size such that it is maximal, and then determine the rules from that. If we can't find a combination of rules that would give this set, we alter the set (reducing the average value) until we find a combination of rules that gives this set.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to approach the problem, and a possible implementation
in R.  It's only a sketch, really; and perhaps a more
constructive method (as indicated by Joseph Wood in the
comments) might give good results as well.

Your dataset, again:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
   Size,  A,  B,  D,  E
      1,  4,  7, -2,  1
      5, -4, -1,  1,  4
     10, -2, -3,  1,  9
     -3,  1,  0,  0, -3
      2,  4, -1,  3, -2
     55,  8, -7,  9,  0
     -5,  3, -4, -1, -5
      2,  0, -2,  1,  8
      1, -5,  1,  8,  1
      4, -9,  3,  2, -3",
  sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

I use a plain data frame here.  For convenience, I
put 'Size' into a separate variable.

```
size <- df$Size
df <- df[, -1]
df

##     A  B  D  E
## 1   4  7 -2  1
## 2  -4 -1  1  4
## 3  -2 -3  1  9
## 4   1  0  0 -3
## 5   4 -1  3 -2
## 6   8 -7  9  0
## 7   3 -4 -1 -5
## 8   0 -2  1  8
## 9  -5  1  8  1
## 10 -9  3  2 -3
```

Now, I allow a filter to be a function that takes a
column of `df` as input, plus possibly a second
argument.  Such a filter must evaluate to a logical
vector with as many elements as `df` has rows.  For
instance, a greater-than relation would use the
function `>`, and the second argument would be the
threshold.  I collect all allowed functions in a list
`functions`.  (The first function in effect ignores the
given colum.)

```
functions <- list(function(x, ...) TRUE,
                  `<`,
                  `>`)
```

A candidate solution `x`, then, is a list of filters (as many filters as there are columns in `df`)
and parameters for those filters. The following
solution does not apply any filter, because for any column that is input, it always returns `TRUE` (i.e. no rows are excluded):

```
x <- list(functions = list(function(x, ...) TRUE,
                           function(x, ...) TRUE,
                           function(x, ...) TRUE,
                           function(x, ...) TRUE),
          parameters = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

A helper function to apply the filters: it returns a
logical vector with as many elements as `df` has rows.

```
subs <- function(x, df) {
    rows <- !logical(nrow(df))
    for (i in seq_len(ncol(df)))
        rows <- rows & x$functions[[i]](df[, i], x$parameters[[i]])
    rows
}
```

We can test this function with `x`. As it should, it
selects all rows of `df`.

```
subs(x, df)
## [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

The strategy for a local search is now to gradually
change the elements of `x`. Whenever such a change
leads to a better solution, we keep it. If it is worse,
we do not accept it.  See [Optimization Heuristics: A
Tutorial](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756) for more details. (Disclosure: I am the author; and I am also the maintainer of the [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF) package that I am going to use below.)

The run such a search, we first need an objective
function. It maps a given subset of rows into an single number, the mean size. Note that the algorithm used later minimises,
so I multiply the objective function's result by -1 (the `-ans` in the last line).  Infeasible solutions (less than 5
rows) get penalised.

```
mean_size <- function(x, df, size, ...) {
    rows <- subs(x, df)
    subset.df <- df[rows, ]
    size <- size[rows]
    ans <- sum(size) / max(1, sum(rows))
    if (sum(rows) < 5)
        ans <- ans - 1000
    -ans   ## to minimise, return 'ans'
}
```

Check: the initial solution selects all rows (but note
the reversed sign).

```
mean_size(x, df, size)
## [1] -7.2

mean(size)
## [1] 7.2
```

And now the key part: the neighbourhood.  The function
picks either a filter or a parameter, and changes it.

```
neighbour <- function(x, ...) {
    stepsize <- 0.5
    rand <- runif(1)         
    i <- sample(length(x$parameters), size = 1)

    if (rand > 0.5) {
        x$functions[[i]] <- sample(functions, size = 1)[[1]]
    } else {
        d <- sample(c(-stepsize, stepsize), size = 1)
        x$parameters[i] <- min(max(x$parameters[i] + d, -10), 10)        
    }
    x
}
```

Now we can run the optimisation.  I use a method called
Threshold Accepting, implemented in the function
`TAopt`.  Threshold Accepting is a special type of local
search; it may also accept changes that lead to
worse solutions, so that it can escape from local
minima.

```
library("NMOF")
sol <- TAopt(mean_size, list(neighbour = neighbour, 
               x0 = x,
               nI = 5000,
               printBar = FALSE,
               printDetail = FALSE),
       df = df, size = size)
sol$OFvalue  ## objective function value of best solution
## [1] -14.8
```

So the best solution found by the algorithm implies a mean size of 14.8.
Since Threshold Accepting is a stochastic method, I run 20 restarts.

```
restarts <- restartOpt(TAopt, n = 20, mean_size,
                       list(neighbour = neighbour,
                            x0 = x,
                            nI = 3000,
                            printDetail = FALSE,
                            printBar = FALSE),
                       df = df, size = size)
summary(sapply(restarts, `[[`, "OFvalue"))
##   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
## -14.80  -14.80  -14.80  -13.18  -10.50  -10.00
```

With the development version of `NMOF`
(https://github.com/enricoschumann/NMOF), you can set
an option `drop0` to `TRUE`. (With the CRAN version, this raises
a warning about `unknown option`, but this is harmless.) This should
improve the reliability of the solution.

```
restarts <- restartOpt(TAopt, n = 20, mean_size,
                       list(neighbour = neighbour,
                            x0 = x,
                            nI = 3000,
                            drop0 = TRUE,
                            printDetail = FALSE,
                            printBar = FALSE),
                       df = df, size = size)
summary(sapply(restarts, `[[`, "OFvalue"))
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##  -14.80  -14.80  -14.80  -14.77  -14.80  -14.60
```

Still, some solutions are likely better than others.  There are
different ways to refine the search, but the easiest
way is to run the method 10 times, say, and to keep the
best solution.

```
best <- restartOpt(TAopt, n = 10, mean_size,
                   list(neighbour = neighbour,
                        x0 = x,
                        nI = 1000,
                        printDetail = FALSE,
                        printBar = FALSE),
                   df = df, size = size,
                   best.only = TRUE)
best$OFvalue
## [1] -14.8
```

So let us look at the actual solution.

```
best$xbest

## $functions
## $functions[[1]]
## function(x, ...) TRUE
## 
## $functions[[2]]
## function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("<")
## 
## $functions[[3]]
## function (e1, e2)  .Primitive(">")
## 
## $functions[[4]]
## function(x, ...) TRUE
## 
## 
## $parameters
## [1] -7.5  0.0  0.5  5.0
```

So, this translates into the following filter:

```
i <- df[[2]] < 0 & df[[3]] > 0.5
```

Looking at the implied mean `size`:

```
cbind(size[i], df[i, ])
##   size[i]  A  B D  E
## 2       5 -4 -1 1  4
## 3      10 -2 -3 1  9
## 5       2  4 -1 3 -2
## 6      55  8 -7 9  0
## 8       2  0 -2 1  8


mean(size[i])
## [1] 14.8
```

As I said, only a sketch; but perhaps it gets you started.

Comment: The real data is in the realms of -0.1 and 0.1, so I adapted:

    neighbour  <- function(x, ...) {
    rand <- runif(1)
    i <- sample(length(x$parameters), size = 1)

    if (rand > 0.005) {
        x$functions[[i]] <- sample(functions, size = 1)[[1]]
    } else {
        d <- sample(c(-0.005, 0.005), size = 1)
        x$parameters[i] <- min(max(x$parameters[i] + d, -0.1), 0.1)        
    }
    x
}
Is this the correct approach? Now we look at the maximum value, on the contrary in order to minimize. What would I need to change?

Comment: First of all, many thanks for the awesome approach (I think I am going to get your book as it seems you implement exactly what I need in R). I tried to apply your approach onto the real dataset with the 2000 rows. What parameters would I have to change in order to refine the search? I increased nI but what else can I do? How big does n have to be? Thank you!!!!

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the first comment: if I understand you correctly, you'll only need to change the steps the neighbourhood function can apply to the filter thresholds. I have update the answer: there is now a variable `stepsize` in the neighbourhood function, and the algorithm will sample from +/- this stepsize. The `rand > 0.5` only means "flip a coin: if heads, change a filter function; if tails, change a threshold".

Comment: Regarding the second comment: it's not primarily about increasing the number of iterations (`nI`), even though this is likely necessary for a larger problem size. But given the size of the problem here, the algorithm should perform much better than it does; it becomes stuck in local minima too often. The simplest way to remedy this, is using several restarts and then keeping the best one, as suggested in the answer. Improving the expected result of a single run will require more analysis (and usually small experiments), starting with the treshold sequence. Could you post a larger dataset?

Comment: Thank you very much for the adaptation, now it is easier. Also the code produces very good solutions indeed after adapting it to your suggestions. If I wanted to do the opposite and calculate the minimal average size. Which code part would I have to adapt and how? Of course I can send you the data but I am new to stockoverflow and I am unsure on how to send it to you. Do you know how it is normally done? Thank you again, this is fantastic.

Comment: If the performance of the algorithm is satisfactory,
there's no need to provide a larger dataset.  With the
development version of NMOF (
https://github.com/enricoschumann/NMOF ), you can set
an option 'drop0'. (With the CRAN version, this raises
a harmless warning, but is harmless.) This should
improve the reliability of the solution.  To minimise,
have the objection function return 'ans' instead of
'-ans'.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your book just arrived this week. :) A small question again regarding the code above. We now have 3 code parts for finding the ideal solution: 2 versions with restarts (with and without the drop0) and one version for finding the best solution. Am I correct in saying that these code parts are not connected (e.g. the result in the "best" part will not get better if the other parts with the restarts are executed). So I could basically only execute the "best" part with more iterations and restarts which will yield the results I need if I am only looking for the best solution?

Comment: Yes, these are different ways to handle the problem. In production code, you would use restarts as well, but only keep the best solution, i.e. you usually use `best.only = TRUE`. (During analysis, it is more useful to look at the distribution of outcomes, so as the get an idea of the potential randomness of the results.)

Comment: The algorithm works very well and I really like the package. Thank you. It came to my mind that it would be nice if additional contstraints could be added. For example, suppose I have a time series spanning several years where not only the overall mean size is maximized (like in the example above) but at the same time every year which the data points are chosen from has a mean of at least a certain threshold. Can this be done with your algorithm and where would I place this condition?