# Filter rows of a dataframe in R with simple rules to optimize the total of a column in R

Tags: r, optimization

```
pacman::p_load("leaps", "tidyverse","caret","magrittr")
data("GermanCredit")
GermanCredit<-GermanCredit%>%mutate(Class=if_else(Class=="Good",1,-1))
```

I have a dataset GermanCredit (see code to replicate the data) and a Class with positive or negative values. (I use this dataset as an example.)
I want to filter rows of the dataset with simple rules (like feature x < number) to optimize the sum of the feature "Class".

So I want to cut out rows with Class -1 without cutting out too many rows with Class 1, so that the sum of Class becomes larger. And that based on simple rules. Is there a simple solution for my problem? Or how can I do this?

Comment: If you want helpful answers, you should provide more information. But in general, you may want to look at classification-tree methods (e.g. package `evtree` on CRAN). Perhaps this answer helps, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377180/finding-ideal-filter-setting-to-maximize-target-function/63429510#63429510

Comment: I tried to make a simple example of the problem I have. 
But in reality I have a dataset with +/-90000 rows & +/-180 features. All features are numeric, but not all scaled in the same range. I expect maybe a couple of filters. 
The answer of the other topic is more or less what I need I guess, so I will have a look if I can use this approach, thanks!